# Conditional Statement Help: Classifying

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

Trying to classify ranges of data as either "Cyst", "Follicle", "GF", or "Unsure" depending on calculated percentiles. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
cyst_percentile = np.percentile(means_c, [45, 55])   #[0.62810152 - 0.64790553]

follicle_percentile = np.percentile(means_f, [45, 55]) #[0.53508696- 0.55220601]

gf_percentile = np.percentile(means_g, [45, 55]) #[0.48250703 - 0.50614147]

#Create an empty list for identification
mean_identification = []

df["Mean Pixel Intensity Identification"] = pd.Series(mean_identification)

#Use a for loop to add to a list that identifies the follicle types
#ASSIGNMENT NOTE: This is not currently working, but should hopefully identify some of the structures
df['Mean Pixel Intensity Identification'] = ""

if (mean_pixel_intensities.any() < cyst_percentile[1]) & (mean_pixel_intensities.any() > cyst_percentile[0]):
    
df['Mean Pixel Intensity Identification'] = "Cyst"

elif (mean_pixel_intensities.any() < follicle_percentile[1]) & (mean_pixel_intensities.any() > follicle_percentile[0]):
    

df['Mean Pixel Intensity Identification'] = "Follicle"

elif (mean_pixel_intensities.any() < gf_percentile[1]) & (mean_pixel_intensities.any() > gf_percentile[0]):

df['Mean Pixel Intensity Identification'] = "GF"

else:

    df['Mean Pixel Intensity Identification'] = "Unsure"

display(df)
```

[Click here to see what my code produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0qjq.png)

It classifies all of my data as "Unsure" when clearly a lot of the data is within the given ranges

Comment: You should try and add your code in the question itself, instead of using a paste service or an image.

Comment: Please [edit] to include your code in the text of your question, not as a picture or link, to make a [mcve]. Please also describe the _specific_ problem you have, as "running into an issue" isn't helpful to the people trying to help you

Comment: Also, replace those ampersands (&) with the actual word `and`. Python doesn't use `&` in these statements.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stack overflow - still trying to figure out how to use this platform.